# How to read dmarc record for a report?

Tags: dkim, spf, dmarc

I have a dmarc file containing some record. I am bit surprised by the result and I would like to make sure I am reading it correctly.

Here is the record:

```
<record>
      <row>
         <source_i>1.2.3.4</source_ip>
         <count>1</count>
         <policy_evaluated>
            <disposition>none</disposition>
            <dkim>fail</dkim>
            <spf>fail</spf>
         </policy_evaluated>
      </row>
      <identifiers>
         <header_from>mydomain.com</header_from>
      </identifiers>
      <auth_results>
         <spf>
            <domain>anotherdomain.com</domain>
            <result>pass</result>
         </spf>
      </auth_results>
   </record>
```

If I am correct, this means that:

this `<source_i>1.2.3.4</source_ip>`: the mail was sent from 1.2.3.4

this  `<count>1</count>` One mail was sent

this `<disposition>none</disposition>` No policy where apply to that mail.

this `<dkim>fail</dkim> <spf>fail</spf>` spf and dkim for that mail failled

this  `<header_from>mydomain.com</header_from>` is the source in the mail header

The other 
`<domain>anotherdomain.com</domain>` the mail was sent to  anotherdomain.com

`<result>pass</result>` the email passed dmarc check.

can you please correct me line ?

Answer (score 2):

What is **auth_results** are DKIM and SPF results, uninterpreted with respect to DMARC.

What is in the **policy_evaluated** are the results of applying DMARC. **disposition** is the policy action specified in DMARC record. **dkim** and **spf** are DMARC-aligned authentications results.

Hope it helps.

Comment: thanks for your answer. Why does the result is `pass` when dkim and spf failed both?

Comment: I suspect that DMARC returns `pass` because the disposition is `none`. That means that your DMARC policy allows all messages, even if they fail SPF/DKIM.